# Install "recordlinkage" module on Windows

Tags: python, pip, scipy, meson-build, record-linkage

I'm trying to use `pip install recordlinkage` to install the recordlinkage library. Till now this command has worked for all other modules I've downloaded like pandas, arrow, etc.

However, I started getting a series of errors since I ran `pip install recordlinkage`. I'm using Python 3.11.1

Initially, I was getting the error -

```
PS C:\Users\x_AMishra\Documents\VA Scripts> pip install recordlinkage
Collecting recordlinkage
  Using cached recordlinkage-0.15-py3-none-any.whl (926 kB)
Collecting jellyfish>=0.8.0 (from recordlinkage)
  Using cached jellyfish-0.11.2-cp311-none-win32.whl (205 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.13.0 in c:\users\x_amishra\lib\site-packages (from recordlinkage) (1.24.2)
Collecting pandas<2,>=1 (from recordlinkage)
  Using cached pandas-1.5.3.tar.gz (5.2 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done
Collecting scipy>=1 (from recordlinkage)
  Using cached scipy-1.10.1.tar.gz (42.4 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Installing backend dependencies ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [37 lines of output]
      + meson setup --prefix=C:\Users\x_AMishra C:\Users\x_AMishra\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-g2nk2241\scipy_cf7f5cd1633b4b07aaf120b334d5ff77 C:\Users\x_AMishra\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-g2nk2241\scipy_cf7f5cd1633b4b07aaf120b334d5ff77\.mesonpy-jp4kzikw\build --native-file=C:\Users\x_AMishra\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-g2nk2241\scipy_cf7f5cd1633b4b07aaf120b334d5ff77\.mesonpy-native-file.ini -Ddebug=false -Doptimization=2
      The Meson build system
      Version: 1.1.0
      Source dir: C:\Users\x_AMishra\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-g2nk2241\scipy_cf7f5cd1633b4b07aaf120b334d5ff77
      Build dir: C:\Users\x_AMishra\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-g2nk2241\scipy_cf7f5cd1633b4b07aaf120b334d5ff77\.mesonpy-jp4kzikw\build
      Build type: native build
      Project name: SciPy
      Project version: 1.10.1
      Activating VS 17.4.2
      C compiler for the host machine: cl (msvc 19.34.31935 "Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.34.31935 for x64")
      C linker for the host machine: link link 14.34.31935.0
      C++ compiler for the host machine: cl (msvc 19.34.31935 "Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.34.31935 for x64")
      C++ linker for the host machine: link link 14.34.31935.0
      Cython compiler for the host machine: cython (cython 0.29.34)
      Host machine cpu family: x86_64
      Host machine cpu: x86_64
      Compiler for C supports arguments -Wno-unused-but-set-variable: NO
      Compiler for C supports arguments -Wno-unused-function: NO
      Compiler for C supports arguments -Wno-conversion: NO
      Compiler for C supports arguments -Wno-misleading-indentation: NO
      Compiler for C supports arguments -Wno-incompatible-pointer-types: NO
      Library m found: NO
     
      ..\..\meson.build:63:0: ERROR: Unknown compiler(s): [['ifort'], ['gfortran'], ['flang'], ['pgfortran'], ['g95']]
      The following exception(s) were encountered:
      Running `ifort --version` gave "[WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified"
      Running `ifort -V` gave "[WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified"
      Running `gfortran --version` gave "[WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified"
      Running `gfortran -V` gave "[WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified"
      Running `flang --version` gave "[WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified"
      Running `flang -V` gave "[WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified"
      Running `pgfortran --version` gave "[WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified"
      Running `pgfortran -V` gave "[WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified"
      Running `g95 --version` gave "[WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified"
      Running `g95 -V` gave "[WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified"
     
      A full log can be found at C:\Users\x_AMishra\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-g2nk2241\scipy_cf7f5cd1633b4b07aaf120b334d5ff77\.mesonpy-jp4kzikw\build\meson-logs\meson-log.txt
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.
```

From what I could figure out, it looked like I was getting errors while installing "scipy" which is dependent on recordlinkage. And from this `ERROR: Unknown compiler(s): [['ifort'], ['gfortran'], ['flang'], ['pgfortran'], ['g95']]` I figured, a gcc compiler was needed to be installed. I did that and the new error that I'm getting is this -

```
PS C:\Users\x_AMishra\Documents\VA Scripts> pip install recordlinkage
Collecting recordlinkage
  Using cached recordlinkage-0.15-py3-none-any.whl (926 kB)
Collecting jellyfish>=0.8.0 (from recordlinkage)
  Using cached jellyfish-0.11.2-cp311-none-win32.whl (205 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.13.0 in c:\users\x_amishra\lib\site-packages (from recordlinkage) (1.24.2)
Collecting pandas<2,>=1 (from recordlinkage)
  Using cached pandas-1.5.3.tar.gz (5.2 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done
Collecting scipy>=1 (from recordlinkage)
  Using cached scipy-1.10.1.tar.gz (42.4 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Installing backend dependencies ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [12 lines of output]
      + meson setup --prefix=C:\Users\x_AMishra C:\Users\x_AMishra\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-i4ll3fah\scipy_50446030ddc0489785aefbfe1a690e40 C:\Users\x_AMishra\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-i4ll3fah\scipy_50446030ddc0489785aefbfe1a690e40\.mesonpy-m4vblvlb\build --native-file=C:\Users\x_AMishra\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-i4ll3fah\scipy_50446030ddc0489785aefbfe1a690e40\.mesonpy-native-file.ini -Ddebug=false -Doptimization=2
      The Meson build system
      Version: 1.1.0
      Source dir: C:\Users\x_AMishra\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-i4ll3fah\scipy_50446030ddc0489785aefbfe1a690e40
      Build dir: C:\Users\x_AMishra\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-i4ll3fah\scipy_50446030ddc0489785aefbfe1a690e40\.mesonpy-m4vblvlb\build
      Build type: native build
      Project name: SciPy
      Project version: 1.10.1
     
      ..\..\meson.build:1:0: ERROR: Could not invoke sanity test executable: [WinError 5] Access is denied.
     
      A full log can be found at C:\Users\x_AMishra\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-i4ll3fah\scipy_50446030ddc0489785aefbfe1a690e40\.mesonpy-m4vblvlb\build\meson-logs\meson-log.txt
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
```

Now the main error seems to be this `ERROR: Could not invoke sanity test executable: [WinError 5] Access is denied.` Along with this I get this Pop up message -
[Pop Up Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eJxZ5.png)

Is there a better way to install recordlinkage? Or is there a way to fix this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Python 3.11 update, there was a big push for [Faster cPython](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.11.html#whatsnew311-faster-cpython), so the behavior overall could be pretty different. I remember when 3.11 came out, I couldn't even `pip install pygame`, because it was incompatible until they updated the `pygame` package. I would recommend falling back to `Python 3.10` then trying it.

Comment: I uninstalled python 3.11 and downloaded 3.10, worked like a charm, thank you!

Comment: @AayushMishra No problem, have fun! :)